# Does another Git Repo (Bitbucket on premise) other than Github not work for 'sbt new OtherGitRepo'

Tags: git, scala, sbt, bitbucket

I want to us `sbt new ..` to create a new project from a *Giter8* template.

The template is hosted in a private *Bitbucket Git Repo*.

It works with plain *Giter8*:

```
g8 https://mycompany.ch/stash/bpf-package-template.g8.git
```

But it doesn't with *sbt*:

```
sbt new https://mycompany.ch/stash/bpf-package-template.g8.git
```

I did not find whether an example nor a statement that this is not possible on the *[sbt documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-new-and-Templates.html#Template+Resolver)*.

Here is the console output:

```
mpa$ sbt new https://mycompany.ch/stash/bpf-package-template.g8.git
[info] Loading settings from metals.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/mpa/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Set current project to my-packages (in build file:/Users/mpa/dev/my-packages/)
[info] Set current project to my-packages (in build file:/Users/mpa/dev/my-packages/)
Template not found for: https://mycompany.ch/stash/bpf-package-template.g8.git
```

**Update**: I created this question: [https://discuss.lightbend.com](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/does-another-git-repo-bitbucket-on-premise-other-than-github-not-work-for-sbt-new-othergitrepo/5628)

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Show the output of the command please. And, when this is a private repo, you have to give credentials to the command, right?

Comment: Note, according to https://github.com/sbt/sbt-giter8-resolver/blob/dc7ab6f95dbc9b9be1da78ba924e98d24d627476/src/main/scala/sbt/Giter8TemplateResolver.scala this should work just fine. The resolver only requires the URI to end with `.g8.git`.

Comment: @cbley I added the console output

Comment: Which version of Giter8 did you use? SBT has integrated 0.11.0 AFAICS, which might mean it is too old. Try running with debug enabled: `sbt -debug new ...`.

Comment: @cbley thanks I created a question on the sbt board - see updated question

Comment: You should include the debug output, this may give some hints. Also, `g8 --version` would be interesting. And, if you have giter8 0.12, it would be interesting when you downgrade g8 to 0.11 and see if that also fails.

Comment: @cbley it even works with 0.10 / `brew upgrade giter8` upgrades to `0.11` - so no `0.12`

Answer (score 1):

It's somehow not hitting the `Giter8TemplateResolver` for 
`sbt new https://mycompany.ch/stash/bpf-package-template.g8.git`, but I think your expectation is right and it should work.

The `isDefined` methos for `Giter8TemplateResolver` is here if you could help debug this - https://github.com/sbt/sbt-giter8-resolver/blob/master/src/main/scala/sbt/Giter8TemplateResolver.scala

Comment: I added a test - and it is defined as expected: `new Giter8TemplateResolver().isDefined(Array("https://mycompany.ch/stash/bpf-package-template.g8.git")) == true`